# Flutter Autofill Service on Android, How to implement

Tags: android, flutter, autofill, password-autofill

Can anyone help with this? See related post: [How to create an Autofill Provider Service using native Android and integrate it into a flutter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603413/how-to-create-an-autofill-provider-service-using-native-android-and-integrate-it). This is exactly what I need answer for. Anyone can help?

I dont know how to call this service. I can enable it in Settings of the phone, but when I click on some field there is no any suggestion even tho I hardcoded UserData username and password

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.